# Does it matter if a function returns a value which we don't need?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, computer-science

For example, if we want a function that adds two values, we can write it using ES6 arrow syntax in two ways:

```
const addShort = () => 1 + 1

const addLong = () => {
    1 + 1
}
```

In first case, we get the return value which is 2, while in the second one, the return value is undefined.

Does the return value from `addShort` has any effect on performance, memory or similar? Should we avoid returning values that we don't need?

Comment: If the compiler doesn't optimize it away, the unused return value could add a bit of extra processing required. But it'll be absolutely irrelevant in 99.9% of situations - better to write clean, readable code than to worry about performance, unless things are running slowly and you need to identify a bottleneck. (but this won't be it)

Comment: Write the function in terms of how you're going to use it.

Comment: If you want to know.... open up the engine's source code and figure it out. I highly doubt it will make any noticeable difference under normal circumstances. With that sample code the engine might not even run your one function since the code does nothing.

Comment: The second version still returns something: it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`const addShort = () => 1 + 1`
is equivalent to
`const addShort = function () { return 1 + 1; };`

But
`const addLong = () => { 1 + 1 }`
is equivalent to
`const addShort = function () { 1 + 1; };`

When you have an expression in a statement like `1 + 1;` (here `1+1` is the expression), the expression is evaluated (is computed) but nothing is done with the result.

There is very little difference between returning it or not in terms of performance.  You should return it if in your context it meaningful to return the result regardless of how the function is used.

Comment: actually, i doubt the unreachable return value expression is even evaluated, and perhaps the function itself isn't even run as a result.

Comment: @dandavis Because there is a possibility of a side effect it will be evaluated (unless there is a optimizer that check for side effect).

Comment: yeah i was thinking about that just now, but i don't think Number primitives can do that, ala the old jsonp array constructor hijacking. pure functions get super optimized these days.